# What word to use as adjective to describe a tracksuit worn with its front-chain open

Tags: adjectives

I've seen `open-front shirt` but it mostly describes a shirt that is supposed to be open in front, as in, it has no buttons. What I'm looking for is an adjective to describe when someone chooses to keep the buttons of their shirt or the chain of their tracksuit open. I thought about using `open-chained` but it reeks of incongruity ("open" and "chain" doesn't really go together).

So, is there an adjective to describe what I mentioned? An example sentence would be: The guy with the _______ tracksuit is the favourite to win this year.

Comment: There is minimal evidence for 'open collar tracksuit', but this may refer to the cut rather than the wearing preference.

Comment: Did you mean the tracksuit *zip*?

Comment: @Weather Vane I naively suspected that fashion had again passed me by.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I wondered too but a quick google shows only *print* pattern designs, although you can get a matching neck chain.

Comment: tracksuits don't have chains. Do you mean zipper?

Comment: The standard idiomatic usage in this area is [***medallion man***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/medallion-man) *- a man who tries to look younger than he is by wearing jewellery and tight clothes, and **who often has his shirt open at the front to show his chest***. We don't normally try to associate this usage with women.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is just added value here.  Anyway, the guys in tracksuits are the underlings, not the head honchos who generally wear suits.

Comment: @GEdgar  according to wiktionary, Finnish has "vetoketju" literally "pull chain".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just describe it using whatever the clasping mechanism is + the prefix *un*. A button-up shirt could be described as *unbuttoned*, and a zip-up track suit could be described as *unzipped*, or a piece of clothing with a drawstring could be described as *untied*.

Comment: Yes, the three terms are good. Closure mechanism, though, not clasp.

Comment: @Lambie A clasp is any kind of device with interlocking parts to fasten things together. Buttons and zippers are both types of clasps, although I agree a drawstring probably wouldn't be.

Comment: Not in my mind: jewelry has clasps. Clothes have fasteners.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?  Found by Google search "unzipped tracksuit".

[image]

Comment: Sure, zipped and unzipped.

Comment: Is there some language where zipper and chain in English have the same translation?  It is not hard to imagine.

Comment: Not in the languages I know.

Comment: I'm questioning whether she'd actually be able to wear that unzipped.